# How can I connect my node.js app to external VOIP provider via SIP?

Tags: node.js, twilio, sip, voip, rtp

I have a node.js app that uses Twilio Bi-directional Media Streams to listen to user (via STT) and send audio back. It works well in US, however Twilio Programmable Voice is not supported in other countries that I need. I have VOIP providers there, but they don`t have anything like Programmable Voice, they only provide SIP credentials to connect SoftPhones.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you should really think twice, after that, twice again about making your own sip/media gateway in your program. It will not be fast nor reliable in node.js. You will spend your time for nothing to support that.

But if you still want, check PJSIPs/libsofia bindings.

The correct way will be to create a control application for well-maintained switches like Asterisk or Freeswitch.